# CSS or HTML Designing

Tags: html, css

Hello All I have the following UI Structure of Images

[image: First Image]

[image: 2nd Image]

Please help me in getting the structure for the images. I have tried the HTML table format to obtain it but didn't get success. Is there any way to get a common CSS to obtain it. Any links or code will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did you try twitter bootstrap?

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: Try bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

Comment: @PabloMartinez: I have tried using HTML table using the colspan but didn't get success in it. So it will be helpful if any help

Comment: What have you tried so far sir???
Take a look at given link,it helped a lot with designing [Metro UI](http://metroui.org.ua/examples.html#__image__)

Comment: @ManojSethi put some code the css you tried, the html table,... sometimes is just a simple correction of what you have tried

Comment: There is easy way to do it. 
here is an [example](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting).  
`1)` copy the style of .row, .col[*], etc. from [http://getbootstrap.com/assets/css/docs.min.css](http://getbootstrap.com/assets/css/docs.min.css) and from [http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css](http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css). `2)` copy the code in span and modify it.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap with using the grid system will help you easily structure the images as you like:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">Place first image here</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">Place second image here</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">Place third image here</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">Place fourth image here</div>
  <div class="col-md-5">Place fifth image here</div>
  <div class="col-md-5">Place sixth image here</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">Place seventh image here</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">Place eighth image here</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">Place ninth image here</div>
</div>
```

For better understand the code, just read through the grid system manual on the bootstrap site.
Its also very easy to create a good looking mobile view with that grid system.

Answer (score 0):

Like all the others I would suggest twitter-bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) so all credit to that answer goes to Zoker.

If you want to code it you could simply do it with divs, margins and floats.

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="box_size_small">

            </div>
            <div class="box_size_medium">

            </div>
            <div class="box_size_large">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
    .box_size_small{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:blue;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
}
.box_size_medium{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:red;   
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
}
.box_size_large{
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:yellow;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
}
```

This was created in a few moments but it should get the idea accross. This is not a versatile solution. You want more versatility? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid